# What is the actual use of toContain() in expect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

As we all know expect replaced with jest. Some property of expect also changes. One of them is toContain which was known as toInclude. You will find it here : https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods/blob/master/src/transformers/expect.js

My problem is when i am trying to use toContain in order to check whether a object match with another object,it showing me error. But earlier with toInclude it was just one line code. So as a replacement of toInclude I find it different,not exact the same.

This array works fine.

```js
expect([2,3,4]).toContain(4);
```

But when i go with object,this error come up

```js
 expect({
        name : 'Adil',
        age : 23
    }).toContain({
        age : 23
    });
```

This is the error

```
Error: expect(object).toContain(value)
Expected object:

{"age": 23, "name": "Adil"}
To contain value:

{"age": 23}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.toContain` is for [checking that an item is in an array](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tocontainitem)

If you want to check the value of an object's property then you can use `.toHaveProperty` - [here are the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavepropertykeypath-value)

so your example would be

```
expect({
    name : 'Adil',
    age : 23
}).toHaveProperty('age', 23);
```

... or to avoid learning another matcher you could just do:

```
expect({
    name : 'Adil',
    age : 23
}.age).toBe(23);
```

Comment: Can toHaveProperty() check multiple object? I was unable to do it. So,I used toMatchObject() for that purpose.By the way toMatchObject() is used to match object,not array.How to match array? In previous version,toInclude served both object and array.

Comment: I don’t think so but you can always have several expect statements

Comment: Okay mate. What about matching array,any suggestion?

Comment: You can use .toContain for arrays

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tocontainitem) (highlights from me):

> Use `.toContain` when you want to check that **an item is in an array**. For testing the items in the array, this uses ===, a **strict equality check**. `.toContain` can also check whether a string is a substring of another string.

So in summary, it tests if an array contains some value(s) or if a string contains a given chain of characters.

To test objects like in your example, you can use:

```
expect({ name : 'Adil', age : 23 }).toHaveProperty('age', 23);
```

Comment: It's showing 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Comment: This one works fine.. expect({
    name : 'Adil',
    age : 23
}).toHaveProperty('age', 23);

Answer (score 1):

Its used when you want to check the existence of an item within an array. Its similar to python's `x in [1,2,3]`. Note that it will not give you the index of the first occurrence. It will just return a boolean